# Roll-your-own unique Email checking in Parse

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, parse-platform

Rolling out my own unique email checking method. Using .equalTo and .find I still get success even with nothing in the DB. I need it to error if there's no match found. Any ideas?

```
  // Check if email is already in use
  var query = new Parse.Query(Email);
  query.equalTo("email", email);
  query.find({
    success: function(results) {
      self.$(".signup-form .error").html("Email already in use.").show();

      this.$(".signup-form button").removeAttr("disabled");
    },
    error: function(error) {
      if (error.code === Parse.Error.OBJECT_NOT_FOUND) {
        alert("Perfect, could not find this email!");

        Parse.User.signUp(username, password, { ACL: new Parse.ACL() }, {
          // ... signUp method here ...
        });
      } else if (error.code === Parse.Error.CONNECTION_FAILED) {
        alert("Uh oh, we couldn't even connect to the Parse servers!");
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: I don't know enough about what this is to tag it with the proper language. Please do so accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find method will return successfully even when no objects are found which meet your criteria. You can check if results has any objects (it shouldn't if the email hasn't been taken), but what you're probably looking for is the [.first() method](https://www.parse.com/docs/js_guide/#queries-constraints).

Comment: Yep, gotcha! Indeed if you know your structure likely has only one match, use first() so you don't need to traverse the array returned by find(). Hat tip is to use if(returnedEmail instanceof Email) to check if you actually have a match instead of a [] empty object.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, have you considered using the actual [User class](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#users) in Parse? This will automatically enforce email uniqueness as well as give you many more important features such as secure password storage, (optional) email verification, a password reset API, access controls, and social integration.

Comment: I want to roll my own because the app rides over email and does not require you to have a user account until you want to. There seemed to be no way to create a 'pending' Parse.User object afaik. Therefore I rolled my own Email class, one or more email objects can then be set at any stage to a User object. Yes if you could loosen up to conditions around the User class and/or have a separate Email class with the extra (awesome!) functions that'd be wonderful.

Comment: On a sidenote, the .first method Héctor suggested still returns 'undefined' on success somehow.

Comment: The JavaScript APIs only allow asynchronous operations since JavaScript is single threaded. first does not _return_ something, it passes the return value to the success function.

Rather than
foo = query.first();
doSomething(foo);

use
query.first({
  success: function(object) { doSomething(object); }
});